# Python Regex unexpected exception. Traceback vs No Match Found

Tags: python, regex

I am practicing regex in Python and want to make sure my code catches errors in the regex and not break. I have found what I see as unexpected behavior.

Log text

```
192.168.2.20 - - [28/Jul/2006:10:27:10 -0300] "GET /cgi-bin/try/ HTTP/1.0" 200 3395
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2006:10:22:04 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2216
```

**Regex script 1**

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(\d)(\d)(a)")
with open("log.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.match( pattern,line)
        if m:
            print(m.group(10))
        else:
            print("no match found")
```

This successfully return "no match found"

```
python parse.py 
no match found
no match found
```

**Regex script 2**

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(\d)(\d)(\d)")
with open("log.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.match( pattern,line)
        if m:
            print(m.group(10))
        else:
            print("no match found")
```

While this return a Traceback error

```
python parse.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(m.group(10))
IndexError: no such group
```

When the regex is `(\d)(\d)(\d)` I get a Traceback.
When the regex is `(\d)(\d)(a)` I do not get a Traceback.

Comment: How is this unexpected? What were you expecting to happen instead? Are you aware that `(\d)(\d)(\d)` matches, but `(\d)(\d)(a)` doesn't?

Comment: BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a useful online tester for regex strings. Gives some useful pointers as to what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, `(\d)(\d)(a)` finds no match => `print("no match found")` fires and the "not found" message is shown.

`print(m.group(10))` is run when no match is found. There are only 3 capturing groups in your regex and as there is no group 10, there is an exception.

Use `print(m.group())` to get the match.

Here is how to get the 10th match safely:

```py
matches = re.findall(r'\d{3}', line)
if len(matches) > :
    print(matches[9])
```